# Gazebo fortress won't load once I add Contact plugin

Tags: ignition-fortress, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have this sdf file:

```
<world name="rl_world">
    <include>
        <uri>path/to/plane.sdf</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>/path/to/robot.urdf</uri>
    </include>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo6-contact-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Contact"> </plugin>
</world>
```

When I try to load in in gazebo with `ign gazebo world.sdf` it shows a blank grey screen with no entities. It doesn't give an error to the console. If I remove the plugin line it loads fine. Is there something wrong with it?

plane.sdf has a contact sensor on its only link and the TouchPlugin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29150/gazebo-fortress-won%27t-load-once-i-add-contact-plugin/) by [Lestes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182673/lestes/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a known issue (https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/796) where having any plugin in your world prevents default plugins from being loaded, so you'll have to add the Physics and ~SystemBroadcaster~ SceneBroadcaster plugins and any other plugins you might need to your world

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lestes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/182673/lestes/) on 2023-06-14**:
Thanks! Working now.
Though for anyone in the future it's SceneBroadcaster. I think 'SystemBroadcaster' was a typo.